# jQuery UI datepicker conflicts with tooltips

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker and the tooltip function from the same collection. Both work perfectly for my application. Except where they both try to work. When I hover on the icons for previous or next months, I get a tooltip popping up that says *"Prev"* or *"Next"*. When I click on the previous-month icon the tooltip stays visible, completely covering the month and year headline. (On the next-month icon it stays visible but it doesn't interfere. Much.)

The function of these icons is absolutely clear without the tooltip, and badly broken with it, but I can't figure out a way to disable the `title="Prev"` and `title="Next"` code.

I actually don't need tooltips anywhere in the datepicker because I'm using it strictly to set a date rather than display events in the calendar.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Do you have any other components on the page that use a different version of jQuery

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script><br>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js"></script><br>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script><br>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script><br>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script><br>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script><br>
<br>
That's from the <head> section of the page. All of it was fetched at the same time.

Comment: jquery-1.8.2.js, jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js, jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.ui.datepicker.js, jquery.ui.accordion.js ===========

That's from the <head> section of the page. All of it was fetched at the same time. Sorry, can't figure out how to get any control over the comments.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to be more specific in the "tooltip" selector.

I changed from:

```
$(document).tooltip();
```

to:

```
$("span.ui-icon").tooltip();
```

And it work for me now.

Answer (score 0):

After initializing my datepickers I use:

`$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').prop('title','');`

Answer (score 0):

You can add option for datepicker():

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
minDate: "-2Y"
});
```